# Why does declaring a delegate as static cause compiler error "The modifier 'static' is not valid for this item"?

Tags: c#, .net, static, delegates

This gives me a compiler error:

```
public static delegate void SomeCoolDelegate();
```

Why?

Comment: Are you trying to make it so that this delegate can only be used to call static methods?

Comment: @Justin: Let's assume yes.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I think what happens is this:

Declaring a delegate is really asking the compiler to create a new special class for you. The job of this class is to act as a function pointer (or multiple function pointers if needed).

The compiler will oblige by creating a new class as you direct with all the things you need to get your job done with the delegate. It will go ahead and create this class, but all the things you are getting are instance level methods and properties, etc.

So declaring a delegate as static is nonsensical (As JaredPar and others pointed out). You are saying 'give me a static class wherein all the guts are not static (and thus unreachable), etc. etc." It doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 6):

That has no meaning for a delegate; I mean, semantically, it's like saying I never want an implementation of this method signature!

You could declare an implementation as static...

```
 protected static SomeCoolDelegate SomeMethod { get; set; }
```

When you mark a class as static, you're saying you never want it instantiated. A delegate is simply a way of identifying a method signature.

Comment: I don't understand. You can mark classes as static to say I never want an implementation of this class. What's wrong with marking a delegate as static, to say "I always want every instance of this delegate to be static"?

Comment: An interesting question; however, a method signature is not defined by it's static-ness; only the input variables, generic declaration, and output type. I don't think there is a method to say "static methods only".

Answer (score 4):

Declaring a `delegate` is declaring a type. Delegates in C# cannot be made `static`. If you want to declare a variable of type delegate, you would do something like this:

```
public delegate void SomeCoolDelegate(); // declare a type called SomeCoolDelegate
public static SomeCoolDelegate foo; // declare foo as an object of type SomeCoolDelegate
```

Comment: This is incorrect. You can declare static classes, and in fact, that's one requirement to making an Extension method.

Comment: Gabe: Thanks, I knew that, but it didn't click for some reason. I feel dumb now. LOL I appreciate the clarification/reminder.

Answer (score 2):

Declaring a delegate is declaring a type.  It makes very little since for a type which contains only instance methods to be declared static.

Answer (score 0):

Delegate is a type, in runtime perspective type is just classification of data store like a folder containing members, there is no point of making a type static because type is static anyway. Member of any type can be static.

C# let's you write static on class to restrict developer to write only static members in type but that does not mean that type is or isn't static.